# Using Include vs ThenInclude

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have been experimenting a little with Entity Framework, and after facing the error below, I tried using ThenInclude to resolve it.

> The expression '[x].ModelA.ModelB' passed to the Include operator could not be bound

But now it seems I lack some understanding of why it did solve the problem

What's the difference between this:

```
.Include(x => x.ModelA.ModelB)
```

And this:

```
.Include(x => x.ModelA).ThenInclude(x => x.ModelB)
```

Comment: There is a string version that lets you pass `"ModelA.ModelB"`.

Comment: `.Include(x => x.ModelA.ModelB)` worked in EF6, but it doesn't work in EF Core. In EF Core you have to use "ThenInclude".

Comment: @RavingDev : I am curious about the reason behind this behaviour on EF Core, is there any article explaining it? I could not find any one.

Comment: In this case there is no difference. What exact EF Core version are you on? Because both work in the latest EFC 2.0.2

Comment: @IvanStoev i'm using EFC 1.1.1

Comment: Then upgrade to a newer version. Earlier EF Core versions have many bugs / improper implementations / limitations which have been fixed in the later versions. Or accept the limitations of the version you are on. There is no explanation / special reason for bugs as you know :)

Answer (score 42):

"Include" works well with list of object, but if you need to get multi-level data, then "ThenInclude" is the best fit. Let me explain it with an example. Say we have two entities, Company and Client:

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public List<Client> Clients {get;set;}
}

 public class Client
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Domains { get; set; }

    public List<string> CountriesOfOperation { get; set; }
 }
```

Now if you want just companies and the entire client list of that company, you can just use "Include":

```
using (var context = new YourContext())
{
  var customers = context.Companies
    .Include(c => c.Clients)
    .ToList();
}
```

But if you want a Company with "CountriesOfOperation" as related data, you can use "ThenInclude" after including Clients like below:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
   var customers = context.Companies
    .Include(i => i.Clients)
      .ThenInclude(a => a.CountriesOfOperation)
    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Please can you help me understand what is the significance of `i` and `a` in `.Include(i => i.Clients)
      .ThenInclude(a => a.CountriesOfOperation)`

Comment: @variable - There is no real significance to those letters.  They are just a shorthand alias to the entity of that collection.  In the above example, `i` represents a `country` and `a` actually represents a `company` as well.  If you don't want to use single letter shorthand, you would write `.Include(company => company.Clients)`

Answer (score 19):

The difference is that Include will reference the table you are originally querying on regardless of where it is placed in the chain, while ThenInclude will reference the last table included. This means that you would not be able to include anything from your second table if you only used Include.