# Is ThenInclude unnecessary?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have just done the following (EF Core 3.1):

```
var aaa = context
   .Table1
   .Include(t => t.Table2.Table3.Table4);
   .Include(t => t.Table2.Table3.Table5);
```

and I have in my variabe `aaa` the elements of Table1 and the ones in all subsequent child tables. I thought a `.ThenInclude` was necessary in these cases. I thought this had to be done the following way:

```
var aaa = context
   .Table1
   .Include(t => t.Table2);
       .ThenInclude(t2 => t2.Table3)
       .ThenInclude(t3 => t3.Table4)
   .Include(t => t.Table2);
       .ThenInclude(t2 => t2.Table3)
       .ThenInclude(t3 => t3.Table5)
```

Is `ThenInclude` not necessary? What is it for, then?

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668851/using-include-vs-theninclude  
In short: ThenInclude() works on collections too.