# Include same entity from multiple different entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a question about Include function in EF6.
I have multiple entities linked to a single entity for example:
SonA, SonB, SonC are all linked to FatherABC entity.
FatherABC has linked entities of his own: BrotherA, BrotherB, BrotherC
Now if I use include like this :

```
    Son son = context.Sons.Where(x => ids.Contains(x => x.id))
        .Include(x => x.Father)
        .Include(x => x.Father.Brother)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Will the include Father/Father.Brother work a single time for all of the entities? since it's the same entity?
Or will it query the data for each of the son entities?

Comment: Execute and try... what is the issue?

Comment: Besides your actual question, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668851/using-include-vs-theninclude

Comment: It should be `.ThenInclude(x => x.Father.Brother)` if we want to drill down to subproperties.

Answer (score 0):

```
Son son = context.Sons.Where(x => ids.Contains(x => x.id))
        .Include(x => x.Father)
        .ThenInclude(f => f.Brother)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

This should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).